# Using dynamic Server and Database Name in SQL Server stored procedure over linked servers

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a requirement.
Using SSIS i am import data from flat file/excel file into my staging table. From staging table i need to filter data and transfer it to different databases over different linked server.i.e. let say for California i have dbCalifornia  on Server A, For Taxes i have dbTaxes on Server B etc etc.
I need to read config table and redirect data accordingly.i.e. if column value =CALI insert data in dbCalifornia.tblA, for column value =TAX insert data in dbTaxes.tblA. I am trying to use Server Name and Database name   as variable (because i am reading these from config table) i.e.

```
INSERT INTO [@server].[@database].[DBO].[BASIC]
```

But i am getting error .
I am not expert DBA please suggest my solution how can i implement this scenario.

TIA

Comment: You should use SSIS to insert the data to the @server.@database directly.  That is what SSIS was made for.  Pushing data through a linked server with SSIS is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using dynamic sql like this:

```
declare @server varchar(100), @database varchar(100);

DECLARE @sql varchar(8000) ='INSERT INTO[' + @server +'].['+ @database + '.[DBO].[BASIC]' + 
'(EmpID,EmployeeID,ADDR1, ADDR2, ADDR3,ADDR4,TELNUM,MARRIED,LNAME,MNAME,FNAME,' + 
'SEX, EMAIL,COUNTRYCODE, CITIZEN) ' + 
'select EmpID,EmployeeID,ADDR1, ADDR2, ADDR3,ADDR4,TELNUM,MARRIED,LNAME,MNAME,FNAME,
SEX, EMAIL,COUNTRYCODE, CITIZEN from dbo.myExcelTable where state = ' + @database;

exec(@sql);
```

I don't understand what are your 100 variables tht you use in your insert,
didn't you say

> if column value =CALI insert data in dbCalifornia.tblA, for column
>   value =TAX insert data in dbTaxes.tblA.
>   ?

So you just need to filter your table using @database value and insert those rows in corresponding table

Comment: can you please give my example for insert statement with variables like   with insert values stored in  variable i.e. employerid etc etc. Because i am getting conversion error. TIA

Comment: Post here your code, I cannot know what your types are, all that you pass within @sql should be STRING.

Comment: I updated my answer but I still don't understand what are your "other" variables, don't you insert ROWS from your table and not variables?

Answer (score 0):

normally when reading a table from another server and DB. I use the LinkedServer, user and table like this:

Select * from Link..User.Table ;

after a linked server I have to use 2 dots.

I don't know if this can help since this is to read from an Oracle database.